# UITableView's indexPath(for cell: UITableViewCell) -> IndexPath? returning nil for visible cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm a little confused as to why this method is returning nil:
`func indexPath(for cell: UITableViewCell) -> IndexPath?`

Here's some debugger output:

```
(lldb) po expandingCell
<MyApp.BankDetailsTableViewCell: 0x7f9ec307da00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 495.01; 414 258); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400003ffc0>>

(lldb) po self.tableView.visibleCells
▿ 8 elements
  ▿ 0 : <MyApp.AddressTableViewCell: 0x7f9ec2e49600; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 207.01; 414 70); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x60800022fc40>>
  ▿ 1 : <MyApp.BankDetailsTableViewCell: 0x7f9ec307da00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 277.01; 414 258); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400003ffc0>>
  ▿ 2 : <MyApp.TransactionLinkTableViewCell: 0x7f9ec585d800; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 535.01; 414 70); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000025e60>>
  - 3 : <MyApp.SeparatorTableViewCell: 0x7f9ec3003000; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 605.01; 414 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000225780>>
  ▿ 4 : <MyApp.GenericFieldTableViewCell: 0x7f9ec3071a00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 649.01; 414 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000226100>>
  ▿ 5 : <MyApp.GenericFieldTableViewCell: 0x7f9ec28eb600; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 693.01; 414 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6080004337a0>>
  ▿ 6 : <MyApp.GenericFieldTableViewCell: 0x7f9ec590c800; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 737.01; 414 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000038b60>>
  ▿ 7 : <MyApp.GenericFieldTableViewCell: 0x7f9ec5849000; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 781.01; 414 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000037080>>

(lldb)
```

You can see that the expanding cell is in the visible list (array index 1).  So why is my code returning nil for this?

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: expandingCell) {

   // NEVER REACHES HERE.  Returns nil            

 } else {
    log.warning("This shouldn't happen.  The indexPath should be returned by tableView!")
 }
```

To give some extra context here, I'm responding to a button press, which should then set a flag on the cell 'isExpanded', and then I call self.tableView.beginUpdates() and .endUpdates() (while providing a new value for heightForRow(at: ...) ) so the cell height expands.

Comment: Where you setup expandingCell?

Comment: as usual. cellForRowAtIndexPath:  Is that relevant?

Comment: Have you used reloadRows inside the beginUpdates & endUpdates?

Comment: Please check frame for your cell , as you mentioned in log. I guess po expandingCell is returning a cell which is not in the View. In visibleCells logs,  it's giving different frame.

Comment: look at the memory address of expandingCell.  It's the same as the cell at array index 1.

I don't call reloadRows.  if you call beginUpdates/endUpdates it will as the delegate for row heights again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really fond of using this method at all so I avoid it at all cost. In your case if you really need that index path I rather assign it when data source requests for a cell. So in `cellForRow` I dequeue a custom cell and assign its data object and its index path.

But in general that is again a bad idea (putting it in other data source or delegate methods make little difference as well) because your data (array of objects for instance) may change while the selection was done (button pressed) and you may find yourself in trouble again.

So what I find the best approach is setting an object to cell and assigning self as a delegate. The cell delegate should get notified that the button was clicked for a specific object which may then be used by delegate to expend the cell... Some code may clarify this procedure:

Assuming you have a view controller that is a data source for your table view and that your table view is showing objects of type `MyObject` so you have some method that will inject these objects:

```
private typealias DataObject = (object: MyObject, extended: Bool) // TODO: use class, not typealias so you can easily change "extended" property for it
private var dataSource: [DataObject] = []
func setDataArray(array: [MyObject]) {
    dataSource = array.map { (object: $0, extended: false) } // TODO: fetch extended from current data source if it exists, else use default
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

So the cell for row would look like:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell...
        cell.object = dataSource[indexPath.row].object
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
```

And height for row:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        dataSource[indexPath.row].extended ? 100.0 : 44.0
    }
```

Now the cell delegate:

```
func myCell(_ sender: MyCell, shouldToggleObjectBeingExtended object: MyObject) {
   if let target = dataSource.first(where: { $0.object === object }) {
       target.extended = !target.extended // To use this you must have a class instead of typealias
       tableView.beginUpdates()
       tableView.endUpdates()
   }
}
```

I can imagine this might be a bit upside-down from what you are having but creating such a system usually pays of greatly. You are completely detached from table view when modifying your source which makes things way simpler and stable. I hope it helps you fix your situation.

As for the "bug" in that method in my experience these always worked a bit funny. There is usually some solution but rarely a pretty one.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to know how to expand cells.  I'm wondering why a cell, which is ALSO in the array of visibleCells, is not causing an IndexPath to be returned.

Comment: @horseshoe7 I know. But I have given you a workaround. Cell being visible or having index path may not be the same. There may be cases where a visible cell will change, go to queue or be dequeued in which cases it probably has no index path. And even if this starts working you should avoid using these kind of methods for multiple reasons of both stability and performance.

Comment: I just assigned an var indexPath: IndexPath? on the UITableViewCell subclass and set it in cellForRowAt... and set it to nil in prepareForReuse.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just answer my own question.  For me this seems like a bug in UIKit, but anyway, I just added
`var indexPath: IndexPath? = nil` to a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and I set it in `-tableView:cellForRowAt:` and set it to nil in `prepareForReuse`

Then I can ask the cell directly what indexPath he represents.

Doesn't seem ideal, but it works.